# using discord.go, how do I retrieve message attachments from a slash command option

Tags: go, discordgo

I'm trying to retrieve attachments and download the contents from a slash command option with the type: `ApplicationCommandOptionAttachment`. My current code:

```
"import-file": func(s *discordgo.Session, i *discordgo.InteractionCreate) *discordgo.MessageEmbed {
    logger.Info(i.Interaction.Message.Attachments)
    logger.Info(i.ApplicationCommandData().Options[0].Value)
    return nil
},
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the contents of an attachment provided through a slash command option. Use the following code.

```golang
func SlashCommand(s *discordgo.Session, i *discordgo.InteractionCreate) {

    attachmentID := i.ApplicationCommandData().Options[0].Value.(string)
    attachmentUrl := i.ApplicationCommandData().Resolved.Attachments[attachmentID].URL

    //get the file contents
    res, err := http.DefaultClient.Get(attachmentUrl)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(errors.New("could not get response from code explain bot"))
        s.InteractionRespond(i.Interaction, &discordgo.InteractionResponse{
            Type: discordgo.InteractionResponseChannelMessageWithSource,
            Data: &discordgo.InteractionResponseData{
                Content: "Could not get response",
            },
        })
        return
    }
```